# Scalable Solution to get latest row for each ID in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a quite large table with a field `ID` and another field as `collection_time`. I want to select latest record for each ID. Unfortunately combination of `(ID, collection_time)` time is not unique together in my data. I want just one of records with the maximum `collection time`. I have tried two solutions but none of them has worked for me:

**First:** using query

```
SELECT *  FROM 
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY collection_time) as rn 
FROM mytable)  where rn=1
```

This results in `Resources exceeded` error that I guess is because of `ORDER BY` in the query.

**Second**
Using join between table and latest time:

```
(SELECT tab1.* 
FROM mytable AS tab1
INNER JOIN EACH 
(SELECT ID, MAX(collection_time) AS second_time 
FROM mytable GROUP EACH BY ID) AS tab2
ON tab1.ID=tab2.ID AND tab1.collection_time=tab2.second_time)
```

this solution does not work for me because `(ID, collection_time)` are not unique together so in `JOIN` result there would be multiple rows for each `ID`.

I am wondering if there is a workaround for the resourcesExceeded error, or a different query that would work in my case?

Comment: Do you have any index on `mytable` table

Comment: You mean other than what I can make by `row_number()`? No, because  BigQuery does not create indexes and I have not appended such field to data before uploading it.

Comment: Ohh I see.. Do you have any other table which has these `ID's`? or Where these ID's got generated ?

Comment: @Prdp I can generate such table by selecting unique IDs from this table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick and dirty option - combine your both queries into one - first get all records with latest collection_time (using your second query) and then dedup them using your first query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tab1.ID) AS rn 
  FROM (
    SELECT tab1.* 
    FROM mytable AS tab1
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT ID, MAX(collection_time) AS second_time 
      FROM mytable GROUP BY ID
    ) AS tab2
    ON tab1.ID=tab2.ID AND tab1.collection_time=tab2.second_time
  )
)
WHERE rn = 1
```

And with Standard SQL (proposed by S.Mohsen sh)

```
WITH myTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS ID, 1 AS collection_time
),
tab1 AS (
  SELECT ID,
  MAX(collection_time) AS second_time 
  FROM myTable GROUP BY ID
),
tab2 AS (
  SELECT * FROM myTable
),
joint AS (
  SELECT tab2.* 
  FROM tab2 INNER JOIN tab1
  ON tab2.ID=tab1.ID AND tab2.collection_time=tab1.second_time 
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(rn) 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID) AS rn 
  FROM joint
)
WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: that's a nice idea, but when I try to test it I get an error that `tab1.ID` cant be find. Do you have any idea how to solve that?

Comment: I re-written you solution as standard SQL and it ran just OK but I wonder what is the problem in BigQuery Legacy SQL

Answer (score 19):

```
SELECT
  agg.table.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(table)
    ORDER BY
      collection_time DESC)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] agg
  FROM
    `dataset.table` table
  GROUP BY
    id)
```

This will do the job for you and is scalable considering the fact that the schema keeps changing, you won't have to change this

Comment: This is really handy. Any good resource to understand how ARRAY_AGG works?

Comment: @dina [reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#array_agg), [guide on use](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/arrays#arrays_and_aggregation)

Answer (score 8):

Short and scalable version:

```
select array_agg(t order by collection_time desc limit 1)[offset(0)].*
from mytable t
group by t.id;
```

Comment: Works very well as step 1 of a de-dup process.

Answer (score 8):

I see no one has mentioned window functions with [`QUALIFY`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause):

```
SELECT *, MAX(collection_time) OVER (PARTITION BY id) AS max_timestamp
FROM my_table
QUALIFY collection_time = max_timestamp
```

The window function adds a column `max_timestamp` that is accessible in the `QUALIFY` clause to filter on.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't care about writing a piece of code for every column:

```
SELECT ID, 
  ARRAY_AGG(col1 ORDER BY collection_time DESC)[OFFSET(0)] AS col1,
  ARRAY_AGG(col2 ORDER BY collection_time DESC)[OFFSET(0)] AS col2
FROM myTable
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: This solution leads to problems if a column has NULL values.

Comment: to skip NULLs use IGNORE NULLS

Comment: this solution is one I looked for quite some time, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, Considering you have a table with unique `ID's` for which you need to find latest `collection_time`. Here is another way to do it using `Correlated Sub-Query`. Give it a try.

```
SELECT id, 
       (SELECT Max(collection_time) 
        FROM   mytable B 
        WHERE  A.id = B.id) AS Max_collection_time 
FROM   id_table A
```

Comment: I think this does what I did in part of my second query by `SELECT ID, MAX(collection_time) AS second_time FROM mytable GROUP  BY ID`

Comment: @S.Mohsensh Its not the same. It will not duplicate the result. Also it is correlated. Did you try my solution

Comment: The query in my comment wont also produce duplicate. 
Duplicate happens in join. I did not try it because subselect is not allowed in BigQuery but it will generate a set of rows with unique (id, collection_time) pairs, won't it?

Comment: Correlated queries are supported using standard SQL only, so the query should work if you uncheck the "Use Legacy SQL" option.

Comment: @Prdp yes I tried your solution and as I guessed it produces a pair of `(android_id collection_time)`,  as my sub-query did. I see that if an index existed, this could help but as I said there no index on the table. And I can't figure out how could it help with no index.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which could be more scalable since it avoids multiple scans of the same table (which will happen with both self-join and correlated subquery in above answers). This solution only works with standard SQL (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" option):

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  (SELECT srow.* 
   FROM UNNEST(t.srows) srow 
   WHERE srow.collection_time = MAX(srow.collection_time))
FROM
  (SELECT ID, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(col1, col2, col3, ...)) srows 
   FROM id_table 
   GROUP BY ID) t
```

Comment: I wasn't able to test the query because error of aggregation function not allowed in `where` clause, and I couldn't rewrite it with `having`.